# Create custom slider block

Tags: 7, javascript

I created custom slider block with nivo slider

here is my code :

```
   <?php
function slider_init() {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'slider') . '/js/jquery.nivo.slider.js');
}
function slider_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
    return array(
        'slider_custom' => array(
            'variables' => array(
                'node1' => NULL,
                'node2' => NULL,
                'node3' => NULL,
            ),
            'template' => 'slider-custom',
        )
    );
}
function slider_block_info() {
    $blocks['slider'] = array(
        'info' => t('Slider'),
        'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
    );

    $blocks['acc'] = array(
        'info' => t('acc'),
        'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,    );

    return $blocks;
}
function slider_block_content(){
    drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module','slider') . '/css/style.css');
    return theme('slider_custom');
}
function slider_block_view($delta = '') {
    $block = array();
    switch ($delta):
        case 'slider':
            $block['subject'] = 'custom nivo slider';
            $block['content'] = array(
                '#markup' => slider_block_content(),
                '#attached' => array(
                    'css' => array(
                        drupal_get_path('module', 'slider') . '/css/slider.css',
                    ),
                    'js' => array(
                        drupal_get_path('module', 'slider') . '/js/slider.js',
                    ),
                ),
            );
            break;

        case 'acc':
            $block['subject'] = 'custoghhghm';
            $block['content'] = 'adhgjgjghsad';
            break;
    endswitch;
    return $block;
}
```

i created .tpl :

```
<div id="wrapper">
<a href="http://dev7studios.com" id="dev7link" title="Go to dev7studios">dev7studios</a>

<div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
        <img src="<?php print drupal_get_path('module', 'slider').'/images/toystory.jpg'; ?>" alt="toystory" width="105" height="105" class="myLink" />
        <img src="<?php print drupal_get_path('module', 'slider').'/images/up.jpg'; ?>" alt="up" width="105" height="105" class="myLink" />

        <img src="<?php print drupal_get_path('module', 'slider').'/images/walle.jpg'; ?>" alt="wallE" width="105" height="105" class="myLink" />

        <img src="<?php print drupal_get_path('module', 'slider').'/images/nemo.jpg'; ?>" alt="Nemo" width="105" height="105" class="myLink" />
    </div>
    <div id="htmlcaption" class="nivo-html-caption">
        <strong>This</strong> is an example of a <em>HTML</em> caption with <a href="#">a link</a>.

    </div>

</div>
```

and js file :

```
(function ($) {
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider();
});})(jQuery);
```

but the slideshow doesn't play

any idea ?

Comment: I would look into Drupal Javascript Behaviors, eg https://drupal.org/node/756722, as most probably your `slider.js` isn't being loaded/initialized correctly.  Failing that, https://drupal.org/project/views_nivo_slider might be a module to look into.

Comment: I would definitely just use Flexslider instead of writing all of this, especially when using with BEAN, it makes it a whole lot easier.